# Windows 7 sets DSCP 0 for all packets

Tags: windows

I am trying to develop my own communication protocol to transmit data packets and I need to set DSCP flag to set the priority for the sent packets. In Windows XP everything works fine, but when I try to make it work in Windows 7, all packets have DSCP = 0. Searching on internet I have tried the following:

- In HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\QoS. If "QoS" folder doesn't exist there - create it.
- Add a REG_SZ parameter named "Do not use NLA" and assign "1" as its value.
- Reboot.

It doesn't work. If anyone know anything about this, all kind of help is welcome!

Comment: Try to set to DWORD:0 DisableUserTOSSetting under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters key,can't check, but at least for windows 10 default is disable

Comment: Already done, but still, it doesn't work... It seems like the OS resets the DSCP automatically but I am sure that there is one way to set my own DSCP.

Comment: Looks, like you can specify 0 for you application using policy, details here at the end of article https://community.rti.com/kb/how-set-dscp-flag-your-system